# Django Rest Framework not allowing Flutter to get Json Response

Tags: python-3.x, django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework

in my Django Project users are required to login before being able to navigate to pages.

In my project I am trying to test Json Response which used to work before adding users in my Django Project.

I am trying to get the api of Django Rest Framework using the following test.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/"));
// print(response.body);
Future<void> main() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Username/items/"));
  final decoded = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map;
  final data = decoded['data'] as Map;
  print(data['name']);
  for (final name in data.keys) {
    final value = data[name];
    print('$name,$value');
  }
}
```

Here is the api.views

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getItem(request, **kwargs):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user)
    items=Item.objects.filter(user=user)
    serializer = ItemSerializer(workouts, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is the api/urls:

```
    path('<str:username>/workouts/',views.getWorkout, name='api_workout'),
```

Here is the serializer.py

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(source="user.username", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model= Workout
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am not sure why I am getting `{detail: Not found.}`:

```
Unhandled exception:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast
#0      main
bin\test.dart:11
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is the Json response:

```
GET /api/Ahesham/items/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user": "Ahesham",
        "active": false,
        "name": "Not Workout",
        "slug": "Not_Workout"
    }
]
```

Here is the setting:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
]}

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True
```

**My question:**

How can I allow flutter to get the data from Django Rest framework?

Why am i getting this error and how can I get access to the api json in the mentioned http?

Answer (score 0):

`decoded['data']` is probably null in your case.

To just avoid the problem you can instead do `as Map?`. But check how your json response looks and then adjust your code to match it.

Impossible for us to say since you have not presented your response.

### Edit

Try to start with this:

```
final decoded = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
```

Then you can loop over the varable named decoded and each object will be a Map from which you can reach `name` and `slug`..

Comment: Sandberg I have added the json response from Django Rest Framework

Comment: There is no field named `data`, so why do you try to decode that as a Map? Is that your expected json response?